# #define change multi-parameter method name

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I have a method

```
- (void)hello:(NSString *)a world:(NSString *)b
```

which I want to rename (using preprocessor macro)

```
- (void)hello_obf:(NSString *)a world_obf:(NSString *)b
```

So I have tried

```
#define hello:world hello_obf:world_obf
```

which actually doesn't work, is there any solution to rename a multi-parameter objective c method using **#define**?

The only solution I have found is to define method name separately, ex.

```
#define hello hello_obf
#define world world_obf
```

which doesn't work for me, as it can mess my other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

Preprocessing happens before any kind of semantic or even syntactic analysis. The preprocessor knows nothing about the *structure* of the programs it is working on, since the structure hasn't been defined yet. So it knows nothing about Objective-C methods.

Basically, the preprocessor takes a stream of tokens as input and produces a stream of tokens as output. Since it does not parse the token stream, it has no concept of Objective-C methods, or C++ templates, or anything else which involves the semantics of an identifier.